# Count item into a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I count in a multidimensional array the number of element with a special condition ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => 'Banana'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => 'Banana'

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item] => 'Cherry'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item] => 'Apple'

        )
)
```

For example, for this array I should find `2` for `Banana`.

Si I tried:

```
$array = array_count_values(array_column($arr,'item'))
echo $array['Banana'];
```

But it's not working.

Thanks.

Comment: chk error reporting, its working fine, getting `Array
(
    [Banana] => 2
    [Cherry] => 1
    [Apple] => 1
)`, i hope this is typo `$array = array_count_values(array_column($arr,'item'))` missing semi colon

Comment: or chk your php version, maybe you are using 5.4

Comment: @devpro: my PHP version is 5.6.29.

Comment: than this will work, as working on my side.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be filtering your array with array_filter according to the requirements, if you're just searching for one keyword.

```
$key = 'Banana'; 
$bananas = array_filter ($arr, function($value) use($key){
    return $value['item'] == $key;
});

$cnt_bananes = count($bananas);
```